# why is my python code not running fully

Tags: python, exit, break

Can anyone help me understand why my very simple rock paper scissors code gets stuck and exits at the end of line 18 please?
I´ve tested each part individually and it works, it might not be the prettiest code but it seems to do the job, however in it´s latest itteration it just exits at the en of line 18, exit code 0, so no error, does´nt say anything is wrong, it just doesn´t execute the next line, like there´s a break or an exit on that line, but there isn´t:

```
 import random

def startgame():
    print("Please choose rock - r, paper - p or scissors - s:")
    pchoice = input(str())
    if(pchoice.lower in ["r","rock"]):
        pchoice = "0"
    elif(pchoice.lower in ["s","scissors"]):
        pchoice = "1"
    elif(pchoice.lower in ["p","paper"]):
        pchoice = "2"
    cchoice = (str(random.randint(0,2)))
    if(cchoice == "0"):
        print("Computer has chosen: Rock \n")
    elif(cchoice == "1"):
        print("Computer has chosen: Scissors \n")
    elif(cchoice == "2"):
        print("Computer has chosen: Paper \n")
#runs perfect up to here, then stops without continuing
    battle = str(pchoice + cchoice)
    if(battle == "00" and "11" and "22"):
        print("Draw! \n")
        playagain()
    elif(battle == "02" and "10" and "21"):
        if(battle == "02"):
            print("You Lose! \nRock is wrapped by paper! \n")
        elif(battle == "10"):
            print("You Lose! \nScissors are blunted by rock! \n")
        elif(battle == "21"):
            print("You Lose! \nPaper is cut by scissors! \n")
            playagain()
    elif(battle == "01" and "12" and "20"):
        if(battle == "01"):
            print("You Win! \nRock blunts scissors! \n")
        elif(battle == "12"):
            print("You Win! \nScissors cut paper! \n")
        elif(battle == "20"):
            print("You Win! \nPaper wraps rock! \n")
            playagain()

def main():
    print("\nWelcome to Simon´s Rock, Paper, Scissors! \n \n")
    startgame()

def playagain():
        again = input("Would you like to play again? y/n \n \n")
        if(again == "y"):
            startgame()
        elif(again == "n"):
            print("Thank you for playing")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Please choose a valid option...")
        playagain()

main()
```

Comment: Try printing the value of battle, and compare it with what you have inside the consecutive if statements.

Comment: Do you have an entry that duplicates the issue?

Comment: There are many issues with the provided code. Some already explained in the answers, some aren't. For example, everywhere you have `.lower` and `.upper` should be `lower()` and `upper()`. Otherwise these `if` conditions will never be `True`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true

Comment: Thank you so much DeepSpace, your comments got me leaps and bounds with the program. Now it all works perfect, Python is such a grammar nazi :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lines like
    `if(battle == "00" and "11" and "22"):`
use `in` operator
    `if(battle in ["00", "11", "22"]):`

`playagain()` is not getting called since none of the conditions are true.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this:

```
if(battle == "00" and "11" and "22"):
```

this will evaluate to `False` in all cases but `00`, you need to change it to:

```
if battle == "00" or battle == "11" or battle == "22":
```

And also the other two statements where you use `and`

Your statement gets interpreted as the following:

```
True/False 1- if battle == "00" 
True       2- and "11" #<-- here it checks if the string is True which means string is not empty
True       3- and "22" is True #<-- here too
```

So your statement will only work if all statements are `True` because you are using `and` which requires all parts of the statement to be `True`. Second and third parts are always `True` so its checking if the choice is `"00"`

What you need is this:

```
1- if battle == "00" True/False
2- or battle == "11" True/False
3- or battle == "22" True/False
```

And you need only **one** part to be `True` here for the statement to run because of `or`